# scratch org connection vs oAuth access token

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, refresh-token, accesstoken

Sometimes I wonder, with the scratch org, even if I use it after 2 days, it still allows to perform certain operations or login(with session id).

But same thing if we followed with oAuth, it doesn't allow more.

Does anyone know how Salesforce manages that, which may allow in certain org-to-org integration to keep oAuth token for long time.

Comment: It is probably doing a token refresh, which you can also do with OAuth. I'm sure you'll find more detail about this if you try doing an internet search.

Comment: yes token refresh I am aware, but in scratch org Cli it is not visible, hence asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SFDX plugin uses an OAuth flow that includes a scope of "refresh_token". This scope allows the client to request a new access token whenever it expires, as long as the refresh token is still valid. You can read more about this flow in the [OAuth 2.0 User-Agent Flow for Desktop or Mobile App Integration](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&type=5) and [OAuth 2.0 Refresh Token Flow for Renewed Sessions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm&type=5).

Comment: refresh flow I'm aware. But in this case CLI has to store it somewhere on the local system right? the refresh-token code.

Comment: @YsrShk It does. See `~/.sfdx/` (bash/Linux) or `%homepath%\.sfdx` (Windows). Each user you're logged in as has its own JSON file that includes the access token, refresh token, login url, etc. These files are where `sfdx force:org:list` comes from.

Comment: Sorry for one more additional question. I checked there client secret is not present in json and in given link its required. am i missing something here?

Comment: @YsrShk The secret isn't used or stored in the User-Agent flow

Comment: okkay thanks for the information!